# How to print actual number when using Aggregate(Max()) in a Django query

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following query set:

```
 max_latitude = Model.objects.aggregate(Max('latitude'))
```

When I print it, it returns `{'latitude__max': 51.6639002}` and not `51.6639002`.

This is causing a problem when I want to add the latitudes together to calculate an average latitude.

If I do `print(max_latitude.latitude)` (field of Model object) I get the following: `error:'dict' object has no attribute 'latitude'`

How can I extract the actual number given from the queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point to the specific field name with

```
max_latitude = Model.objects.aggregate(Max('latitude'))['latitude__max']
```

You can also name your field as you want:

```
max_latitude = Model.objects.aggregate(latitude=Max('latitude'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a dict, use

```
max_latitude['latitude__max']
```